# How to completely remove Postgres from macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, postgresql, uninstallation

I'm on macOS Sierra and have had issues with installing Postgres. I installed it with `brew` and with the Postgres.app native app from postgresapp.com

After using `brew uninstall postgres` and following Postgres.app's uninstallation instructions from their website. I'm still seeing the a 'PostgreSQL' user on my machine and when I run `sudo find / -name "*postgres*"` I still see a lot of output (some is pgAdmin4 and Postico which I'm happy to keep, since I'll be postgres soon), much of which is in the `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6` directory including an actual postgres binary.

Is it safe to just remove the entire directory? How do I completely remove Postgres from my machine so I can start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `brew uninstall postgres`, removing postgres.app, and removing the other postgres stuff (that came from https://www.postgresql.org/) in the terminal, my computer worked properly for months and reinstallation went smoothly, too.